# Drools nested aggregation

Tags: java, jboss, drools, rules, rule-engine

I have the following rule in drools. What's happening is that the `$expense` is evaluated on a per card basis. But I want it to be evaluated on a per user basis (The `$u`).

```
rule "test":

when
    $u: User()
    $card: Card(user_id == $u.id)
    $expense: Double() from 
         accumulate (
             $transaction: Transactions(
                   card_id == $card.id,
                   transaction_date >= 'startDate',
                   transaction_date <= 'endDate'
         ),
         sum($transaction.amount)
then
    // do something with expense. 
    // but I want to the expense to be the expense for a user. not a card.
end
```

Comment: I managed to implement this by creating a composite declared type only for the purpose of my rules. I also declared an instantiated a "agg" fact, that was used to store the total expense.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need a user ID field in the Transactions for this to work. In that case you cam remove the card from the rule so it will work on a user basis.

Comment: yes. that is correct. but it's also possible to do this without touching the facts inserted in to engine from the rules driver and declare the required facts in the rules file itself. And then use these declared facts for the computation. That is what I did, because modifying the external facts wasn't an option that we wanted to go with.